# 型 T[] は (ReadOnly)Memory<T> に代入可能？

Tags: c#, .net

あるライブラリのコードを調査していて、`(ReadOnly)Memory<T>` という型の存在を知りました。
次のようなコードを考えています。

```cs
using System;

internal class Program
{
    static void f1(Memory<int> data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }

    static void f2(ReadOnlyMemory<int> data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }

    static void f3<T>(ReadOnlyMemory<T> data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new[] { 0x42, 0x43, 0x44 };

        // case 1. OK
        f1(new Memory<int>(array));
        // case 2. OK
        f2(new ReadOnlyMemory<int>(array));
        // case 3. NG
        //f1(new ReadOnlyMemory<int>(array));
        // case 4. OK...?
        f2(new Memory<int>(array));
        // case 5. OK
        f1(array.AsMemory());
        // case 6. OK...?
        f2(array.AsMemory());

        //----------------------

        // case 7. OK, why??
        f1(array);
        // case 8. OK, why??
        f2(array);
        // case 9. NG, why??
        //f3(array);
    }
}
```

ここで、case 1-6 はおおむね予想の範囲でしたが、それに対して

- case 7,8 がコンパイルエラーにならない理由
- ↑を踏まえたうえで、case 9 がコンパイルエラーになる理由

を知りたいです。

補足: `.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: 7,8は、MemoryおよびReadOnlyMemory側に[暗黙的な変換演算子](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.readonlymemory-1.op_implicit?view=net-6.0#System_ReadOnlyMemory_1_op_Implicit_T____System_ReadOnlyMemory__0_)が定義されているからです。

case 9については、解決ルールは説明できませんが、もし`f3`を呼び出したいのであれば、エラーメッセージに従い`f3<int>(array);`としてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### case 7,8 がコンパイルエラーにならない理由

```
public static implicit operator Memory<T> (T[]? array);
public static implicit operator ReadOnlyMemory<T> (T[]? array);
```

が存在し暗黙の型変換が行われるからです。（[`Implicit(T[] to Memory<T>)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.memory-1.op_implicit?view=net-6.0#System_Memory_1_op_Implicit_T____System_Memory__0_)と[`Implicit(T[] to ReadOnlyMemory<T>)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.readonlymemory-1.op_implicit?view=net-6.0#System_ReadOnlyMemory_1_op_Implicit_T____System_ReadOnlyMemory__0_)）

#### case 9 がコンパルエラーになる理由

`Implicit(T[] to ReadOnlyMemory<T>)`が定義されているのは`ReadOnlyMemory<T>`側であり、`Array`ではありません。そのため、

```
int[] → ReadOnlyMemory<int>
```

への変換はできますが、

```
int[] → ReadOnlyMemory<T>
```

への変換はできません。`f3<int>`と型を明示することで要求される引数も`ReadOnlyMemory<T>`から`ReadOnlyMemory<int>`と明示されるため、変換可能となり呼び出しも可能になります。

もし、`Implicit(T[] to ReadOnlyMemory<T>)`が`Array`側に定義されていたら型推論できたのですが、こればっかりは仕方がないかと。